# How to apply a model for each value in the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have big data on production values of farmers (shapefile). Each farmer has a number of parcels in the attribute table. I try to apply a model for each farmer in the attribute table. The model simply following the steps below:
1- Feature to point (input: parcels)
2- Minimum bounding geometry (convex hull; input: output of feature to point' output)
4- Feature to point (input: minimum bounding geometry output)
5- Point distance (this step is to calculate the distance between the center of minimum bounding geometry and the center of parcels)
Note: The model is also attached for a farmer but we want to apply the model for each farmer. You can see the structure of the attribute table with the farmers code (tootja) as well[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need a model to compute this.

Comment: How I can do it then? Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a copy of your shapefile. Run !shape!. convexhull() on field shape. Add geometry attributes, centroid to both Join 2 tables using polygon unique id, use Pythagorean to compute distance, or math.hypot(dx,Dy). Dissolve by farmer 1st.

Comment: Maybe your way is easy but I couldn't understand. I have about 300 farmers data, so I need to do it for each farmer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the iterator called "iterate feature selection" with your field TOOTJA_ID as input. Right-clic in the window of your model, then select iterator in the contextual menu.

You can also export your model to python and loop on the unique values of your field, but this is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where I should use "iterate feature selection" ? Could you say which part I should use it in the model?